# A simple way to measure relative speed of a method in simulator?

Tags: ios, performance

I have a very heavy method that uses many variables and that requires a lot of testing. For reasons that don't really matter, I'm developing on several different machines (Mac Pro, MBP, etc) and therefore I know the simulators will run at different speeds on each machine.

Is there a simple way to evaluate the relative speed of this method that will be consistent regardless of the hardware I'm on? And without using Instruments?

Something like using CACurrentMediaTime() would be great, but that's obviously effected by hardware speed.

It doesn't even need to give me an exact time, I just need to know if A set of variables is what speed relative to B set of variables.

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this and I'm just missing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just run the code on an actual device instead of a simulator?  Or only use one machine at a time for each set of tests?

Comment: Because of the sheer number of tests and iterations I need to run. I just thought there might be a simple way that I was overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to define some processor-intensive reference function to compare it to (e.g. factoring a moderately sized prime or taking lots of square roots).  Then each time you test your method, you would time it with CACurrentMediaTime() and then also run and time the reference function.  You could then use the ratio of your method's run-time to the reference method's run-time as your metric.

Assuming your method is CPU-bound (or at the very least, the difference in run-time for your method between different machines is primarily CPU-dependent), this should give you what you're looking for.